# Probability expected value for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

Here's something I have problem with:

> A proofreader checks mistakes in a book. He corrects the ones he could find and relays the book to the author. The author also checks his book for
>   mistakes, and passes it to the proofreader. The probability of finding a mistake by the proofreader is
>   0.9 (independently from other mistakes) and by the author is 0.5. Let's assume the initial amount of mistakes equals 500. What is the
>   smallest number of correting rounds (the proofreader's + the author's
>   checks) to be sure that with the probability greater than 0.6 the book
>   doesn't contain any mistakes. 
>   (the original text is in Polish, I hope I
>   translated it well).

I came up with something like this:
EV (expected value of Poisson distribution) = np, where n is the number of mistakes and p is the combined probability of finding the mistake

1st round:
EV1 = 500 * 0.45 = 225 - the amount of remaining mistakes
2nd round:
EV2 = 225 * 0.2025 ~ 46 
3rd round:
EV3 = 46 * 0.911 ~ 4
4th round:
EV4 = 4 * 0.041 ~ 0

So after 4 rounds the book should not contain any mistake.
BUT I don't use this assumption of probability greater than 0.6 and this is what makes me think I might have something wrong. Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After each double round, the proportion of remaining mistakes should be about $0.1\times 0.5=0.05$ times the previous number.  So your expected values should be about $25, 1.25, 0.0625, 0.003125$ and four rounds is probably too many.

After four rounds, the probability a particular mistake remains is $ 0.05^4 = 0.00000625$ so the probability of no remaining mistakes is $(1-0.00000625)^{500}\approx 0.999975$ which is much more than $0.6$ and so four may be too many.

Instead try to solve $(1-0.05^n)^{500} \ge 0.6$, i.e. $n \ge \dfrac{\log(1-0.6^{1/500})}{\log(0.05)} \approx 2.3$.  You need $n$ to be at least this big and an integer so three rounds would be enough.